# Order of repeated segments

Tags: edi, x12

Is the order of repeated segments in `EDI` important. For example, if the implementation guide suggests `DTP` segment with Date/Time Qualifier `401` to be followed by `DTP` segment with Qualifier `404`, is it required for these segments to be in that order? Or is it right to have them in reverse order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order shouldn't matter, unless the trading partner is expecting a certain order (They shouldn't, but I have seen it where the trading partner will be looking for the first segment instead of looking for the qualifier.)

Answer (score 1):

The DTP segments can be in any order.

Comment: I mentioned DTP as an example. Is it right in case of any segment to keep segments of a loop in any order?

Comment: Repeating segments can be in any order.  Generally speaking, mapping is done so that the order doesn't change, but if you're asking if the qualifiers have to come in a certain order, they do not.  So DTMs can be in any order.  MSG can be in any order. N1 can be in any order, etc.

Comment: @Abin, depends. I have seen MIG's where eg LIN's are supposed to be numbered sequential. For DTP, DTM, NAD order does not matter. In general: check the MIG. If it is not mentioned, order does not matter.